# let hibernate entity generator generate primary data type instead of object type

Tags: java, hibernate, maven

i am using hibernate-entity-generator (maven plugin) to generate entity class from database tables.

All the data type in generated entities are object types, how to let hibernate generate primary types instead of object type?

for example, i have a user_data_profile table (mysql):

```
+--------------------+------------+
| Field              | Type       |
+--------------------+------------|
| id                 | bigint(20) |
| login_times        | int(11)    |
| work_apply_times   | int(11)    |
| work_done_times    | int(11)    |
+--------------------+------------+
```

the generated entity class is like this:

```
public class UserDataProfile {
    private Long id;
    private Integer loginTimes;
    private Integer workApplyTimes;
    private Integer workDoneTimes;
}
```

what i actually want is this :

```
public class UserDataProfile {
    private long id;
    private int loginTimes;
    private int workApplyTimes;
    private int workDoneTimes;
}
```

Comment: Which problems are you facing with Wrappers instead of primitive types ? At the very least, you don't wish your ID to be primitive.

Comment: Also, if you want your fields to be primitive types, the corresponding columns should have a non-null constraint (I'm not saying this will make the generator do what you want, though. To me, auto-generated entities are an absurdity).

Comment: @John , the biggest problem by using wrapper types is : i need to add many null check into my code to avoid NullPointException when i am trying to get the value from my entities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i find the solution, and post it here.
Hope it can help others.

To make hibernate entity generator generate primary types instead of wrapper objects, we need to configure a type-mapping in "hibernate-reverse-engineering" config file. For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-reverse-engineering PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Reverse Engineering DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-reverse-engineering-3.0.dtd" >
<hibernate-reverse-engineering>
    <schema-selection match-schema="user"/>
    <!-- use type-mappings to mapping jdbc type and hibernate type -->
    <type-mapping>
        <sql-type jdbc-type="BIGINT" hibernate-type="long"/>
        <sql-type jdbc-type="INTEGER" hibernate-type="int"/>
    </type-mapping>
    <table schema="user" name="user">
        <primary-key>
            <key-column name="id"/>
        </primary-key>
    </table>
</hibernate-reverse-engineering>
```

Comment: This enforces all Longs and Integers to be primary types (from that class)... This should only be the case for non-nullable columns